# Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this is the common question in this forum, but I tried last nearly 4 hours one by one not working for me. Worked before another method & another resource but not in this method.

Error below:

**Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/Data.pdf**

When I use like below: **Static File**

```
@file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/Data.pdf")
```

Then

```
File.new(@file)
```

That is working but when like below:

**Dynamic File**

```
@file = File.open("#{papers.paper.url}") #=> output url: https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/Data.pdf
```

Then

```
File.new(@file)
```

That is showing error. I have tried string like `w` `w+` `r` `r+` etc.

What I'm doing wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: So you're wondering why `File.open` won't open a remote file over HTTPS?

Comment: Yes that is confusion

Comment: Can you try `@file << open("#{papers.paper.url}").read`

Comment: How are you authenticating to access your S3 bucket?